# Leave all logs from users who have specific log (r language)

Tags: r

I have my table like this(input):

```
User   Event

Mike   error
Mike   buy
Bony   error
Bony   like
Mike   rate
Mike   like
```

I need to leave all logs from users who do not have `rate` in Event(output):

```
User   Event

Mike   error
Mike   buy
Mike   rate
Mike   like
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: What have you tried? Why did it not work? Shouldn't Mike be removed since he has `rate` in `Event` not `Mike`?

Comment: Sorry for my english! Mike should stay because he has log with "rate"!  And we remove Bony because she hasn't!

Comment: @RonakShah yeah sorry! Have I edit my question?

Comment: Maybe `df1[ df1$User %in% df1[ df1$Event == "rate", "User"], ]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution can be :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(User) %>%
   filter(sum(Event == 'rate') > 0)

#   User  Event
#  <fctr> <fctr>
#1   Mike  error
#2   Mike   buy
#3   Mike   rate
#4   Mike   like
```